# How to add labelfield on above Imagefield in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

i've one imagefield. i want to show label field on that image filed.

How to show this on blackberry.

i expected like this image.

How to add label field with white background with fill 50%(for transparent effect).

if any sample code snippet. pls give.

[image]

Comment: Several questions: 1) what did you try? 2) what is your target OS version?

Answer (score 1):

Have a Field Manager, and override its width and height by methods sublayout method. and set image as background of this layout.

Now add a label field over this. and Set its background to some semi transparent color, by setting alpha.

Havent applied myself yet, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't provide any snippet. There are two possible solutions:

1. Use `AbsoluteFieldManager` put `ImageField` on it and put `LabelField` with transparent background and font color on the top (OS 5+)
2. Override paint in `ImageField` and after call `super.paint()` draw your text with transparent background.

The additional keywords for cases:

1. `BackgroundFactory`, `Field.setBackground()`
2. `Graphics`